# How to build search URL pagination in Laravel 5.2?

Tags: php, arrays, pagination, laravel-5

Here is my view (html) of the form:-

```
{{ Form::open(array('url' => '/search/','method'=>'get', 'id'=>"search_form_header",'name'=>"search_form_header"))}}
<div class="filter_clumn">
    <ul>
        <li><strong>Looking for</strong></li>
        <?php foreach($diningType as $keyDining=>$ditypeval){ ?>
        <li>
            <div class="checkbox">
              <label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="looking_for[]" id="looking_for_<?php echo $keyDining;?>" value="<?php echo $ditypeval->id;?>" <?php if(isset($requestLookingFor) && in_array($ditypeval->id, $requestLookingFor))  echo "checked";?>/>
                <span class="cr rightcr"><i class="cr-icon glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i></span>
                <?php echo $ditypeval->name; ?>
              </label>
            </div>
        </li>
        <?php } ?> 
    </ul>
</div>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn yel_btn big_btn" onclick="document.getElementById('search_form_header').submit()">Apply</a>
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

The user can select multiple checkbox and hence, the checkboxes are taken as array. So the URL after form submit is

```
http://demotest.com/laravel/demo_project/public/search?looking_for[]=1&looking_for[]=2&looking_for[]=3
```

or in raw-url:-

```
http://demotest.com/laravel/demo_project/public/search?looking_for%5B%5D=1&looking_for%5B%5D=2&looking_for%5B%5D=3
```

Now, the code is working fine and I can get desired data. The problem is while creating pagination links:-

In html, the pagination is set like this:-

```
@if (!empty($link))
<div class="col-sm-12">
{!! $link->appends($urlString)->links() !!}
</div>  
@endif
```

The $urlString is an array which the laravel technology uses to create pagination URL. In laravel, the array is in this form:-

```
array('param1'=>'param_value1', 
'param2'=>'param_value2',
'param3'=>'param_value3'
);
```

But since I am using looking_for[] as an array, my array must be like:-

```
array('looking_for[]'=>'1', 
'looking_for[]'=>'2',
'looking_for[]'=>'3'
);
```

Note that the key are same/repetitive which is **not allowed in PHP**. I am creating the array like this after the form submit:-

```
$dining_ids = $request->input('looking_for'); 
foreach($dining_ids as $di)
{
    $urlString['looking_for[]'] = $di;
}
```

But instead of creating

```
array('looking_for[]'=>'1', 
'looking_for[]'=>'2',
'looking_for[]'=>'3'
);
```

the array is becoming

```
array('looking_for[]'=>'3'
);
```

Taking only the last value, may be **overwriting the key value** instead on inserting a new **key** with same **key_name**. What other way can I fix this problem?

Comment: why don't you use post? it will bring all the value as an array

Comment: Actually, get method are "prefered" for search procedures for SEO. I can share/send the search URL (with parameter) to someone and they can see the result directly.

Comment: Get is suitable, can you share any source of this info?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some studies, I have found the solution to the problem. Others may face such problem, so I am chronicling the answer here.

The problem was manually creating the array:-

```
array('looking_for[]'=>'1', 
'looking_for[]'=>'2',
'looking_for[]'=>'3'
);
```

One solution is to change

```
{!! $link->appends($urlString)->links() !!}
```

into the following:-

```
{{ $link->appends($_GET)->links() }}
```

The above code automatically puts the `$_GET` params into the pagination urls.